# Tomcat: How to stop a servlet without restarting the whole container?

Tags: tomcat, jboss

One way is to put a dummy jar and let the hot-deploy handle it (loading the dummy jar instead of the real servlet). I wonder if there is an easier way without bothering with dummy jars (in JBoss maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

JBoss has a deployment scanner that will notice if you remove the jar, and undeploy.

Comment: Ok. And what about Tomcat ?

Comment: You can accomplish the same effect with the tomcat manager, http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Undeploy%20an%20Existing%20Application.  That will remove stop your webapp & remove all of its artifacts.